# using jquery to find value of hidden form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone has he answer to my problem...

I'm trying to use jquery to find the value of different hidden fields on a form. My problem is I have multiple forms appearing on the same page (items of a result set for updating) and the jquery only finds the value of the first field. When I click on the div to update the field I only get the ID of the first record.

Here is my code

repeated html

```
<ul class="task-container-item">
    <form id="task-submit" method="post" name="form">
        <input class="taskID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $taskID;?>">
        <li><?php echo $name;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $date;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $creator;?></li>
        <li class="description"><?php echo $description;?></li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.task-container-item').click(function(){
         $(this).css("background","green")
         $(this).css("color","#fff");
         var taskID = $(".taskID").val();
         alert (taskID);
    });
});
```

Hope you can help

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on the list of elements with given class:

```
var taskIDs = [];
$('.taskID').each(function() {
  taskIDs.push($(this).val());
});
```

You'll have all the ids in the `taskIDs` array

**update**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.task-container-item').click(function(){
        $(this).css("background","green")
        $(this).css("color","#fff");
        var taskID = $(this) // Use the element that has been clicked on
                      .find(".taskID") // find the .taskID element in that
                      .val();
        alert(taskID);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and after clicking on the divs I still get them all displaying the ID of 1, despite the HTML showing the value of the hidden field as their ID from the database.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your goal. I've added a new suggestion that supposed to do what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have php increment the forms' inputs' id.

For instance:

```
<input class="taskID" type="hidden" id="taskid-1" value="<?php echo $taskID;?>">
```

and then for the next input

```
<input class="taskID" type="hidden" id="taskid-2" value="<?php echo $taskID;?>">

for(var x=0;x<?php echo $total_forms; ?>;x++){
    //your processing code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input[type=hidden]')
```

Then you could use `.each()` for each hidden field.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean please? This is my first real delve into anything jquery.